# Qt qmake keep generating mingw32-make.exe process

Tags: qt, mingw32

I have a Qt project, it stops working after some source code changes, and the project is stuck when I try to compile and qmake keeps generating "mingw32-make.exe *32" processes, endlessly. Here is the compile output. Anyone has any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

> 21:13:01: Running steps for project XYZ... 21:13:01: Starting:
>   "C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" D:_Project\XYZ.pro -spec
>   win32-g++ 21:13:07: The process "C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe"
>   exited normally. 21:13:07: Starting:
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
>   C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile
>   ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o
>   Makefile ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++
>   -o Makefile ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe
>   -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile
>   ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ -o
>   Makefile ..\XYZ.pro C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-g++
>   -o Makefile ..\XYZ.pro Makefile:214: recipe for target 'Makefile' failed mingw32-make: *** [Makefile] Interrupt 21:16:25: The process
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code -1.
>   21:16:25: Canceled build/deployment. 21:16:25: Elapsed time: 03:24.

Additional information following the first comment... I thought shorten the path fix the problem but it did not... Now I change to source code to "D:_Project\test\code" and make the build directory "D:_Project\test\build-Client". These seem short enough but I'm still having the same problem... Need more help. Thanks.

```
23:11:32: Running steps for project Client...
23:11:32: Starting: "C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" D:\_Project\test\code\Client.pro -spec win32-g++
23:11:33: The process "C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
23:11:33: Starting: "C:\Program Files\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
"C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe" -spec win32-g++ -o Makefile ..\code\Client.pro
23:11:52: The process "C:\Program Files\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code -1.
23:11:52: Canceled build/deployment.
23:11:52: Elapsed time: 00:20.
```

Comment: I would recommend that the route is not long, generally the above will generate this error.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix the problem!